# Excel import automation

Tags: c#, .net, excel, import-from-excel

I've come to a complete standstill: I need to import data from Excel to a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 database. Certain columns, starting at specific rows, contains data information that I need to extract and properly insert into the database, and the file itself is provided as a stream.

I've been looking into Microsoft's solution *Excel 12.0 Object Library*, but it seems dependant on Office being installed in the production environment? Or is it possible to deploy an application to an environment where Office is not installed?

I've also cast a glance upon [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/), but it doesn't seem to function for *xlsx* or Office 2010-documents, complaining about *a 'bad file signature'*.

What are your recommendations?

Comment: Manually or programmatically? One time or recurring? Easiest way is to save the file, then in Mgmt Studio right-click the database root and choose Tasks->Import Data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) should be fine. Have you used:

```cs
//2. Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
```

to open your xlsx file?

Comment: I did, but the Excel-file that I was using was apparently corrupt! Thank you for making me try again!

Answer (score 1):

I use  [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx)  for parsing excel files. Normally, yes, the computer deployed to would need to have Office installed, which would put the Interop libraries in the Global Assembly Cache. I get around this by copying the DLL in with the deployment project. You could also try embedding the interop library in to your assembly.

Here's an example using interop: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

Answer (score 1):

If you're just reading in the data and it's known what you want out of it, I typically just used OLEDB to read in the data and then do what I need to with that.

Quick sample using a DbDataReader to quickly go through the rows, giving a [ConnectionString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel#p84) and SheetName

```
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.OleDb;

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
    connection.Open();
    using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "]";
        using (DbDataReader DR = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (DR.Read())
            {
            // Read your data here.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A different [example](http://codehill.com/2009/01/reading-excel-2003-and-2007-files-using-oledb/) can be found here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The problem with this approach is that I would probbably have to store the file temporarily to the server whilst performing the import procedure? The file is received as an input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a chance to try: http://spread.grapecity.com/spread-services/ or https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spread.Services/? 
It gives you a comprehensive API to manipulate Microsoft Excel-compatible spreadsheets without MS office installed in target machines.